# How to run "cd" command and keep ssh session in mosh

Tags: ssh, mosh

In ssh, I can use `ssh root@myhost -t "cd mydir; bash -i"` to do that, how can I run **2** commands in mosh with one line

Answer (score 0):

According to [`man mosh(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mosh), you can do the same with `mosh`, but you need to add the `-t` option to the ssh:

```
mossh root@myhost --ssh="ssh -t" "cd mydir; bash -i"
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when i type `mosh root@rmt --ssh="ssh -vvv -t" "cd ~; bash -i"`, it return "debug1: Exit status 1
/usr/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message.", but mosh-server has running in server, when i type `mosh root@rmt`, it work.

Comment: and what about trying `mossh --server="cd mydir; mosh-server" root@myhost` ?

Comment: even I try `mosh --server="cd /tmp; mosh-server" root@rmt`, the startup dir still in "~/"

Comment: final thought: `mossh --server="mosh-server -- 'cd mydir; bash -i'" root@myhost`. It must work

Comment: even worse, when i run `roroco@roroco-Zhaoyang-K49 ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_plans $ mosh --server="mosh-server -- 'cd /tmp; bash -i'" root@rmt`, it show "[mosh is exiting.]"